# MySql insert where values don't exist withoout unique keys

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
TableA
-----------
id | propertyA | propertyB
```

How can insert new row into table if row with propertyA and propertyB don't exist yet? PropertyA and propertyB are not unique so I can't use replace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to 'insert if not exists' in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql)

Comment: "PropertyA and propertyB are not unique", did you mean the combinatioin of A and B is not unique? or seperatly?

Comment: both. they are not defined as unique in any case

Answer (score 0):

You proberly can use somthing like:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(propertyA, propertyB)
SELECT :a, :b
FROM DUAL
LEFT JOIN TableA ON (propertyA = :a AND propertyB = :b)
WHERE TableA.id IS NULL;
```